# How to lift sails on url with no port?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, sails.js

When we lift the sails it either takes its default port 1337, or the port which we mention. e.g. http://localhost:1337/

But I want to run sails server on url without port e.g http://localhost/, how can we achieve this?

Comment: You might want to run your server at port 80, since is the default port. But you won't have permission for that, you need to use ( apache / ngnix )  to listener at :80 and redirect the flow to your :1337

Comment: You don't need apache/ngnix... You just need to allow port 80 for node... On ubuntu systems:
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/bin/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a port while lifting the server by passing `sails lift --port 9000` or any port you wish.

If you want to deploy the sails project in an EC2 instance, I would recommend using nginx as reverse proxy and transfer the request to your app running in some other port.

You can start looking into these examples

http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/javascript/nodejs/using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-in-front-of-your-node-js-application/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04